# Eiffel Bridge Design

Tags: structural-engineering, bridges

In bridge design normally base supports are strong,fixed/rigid. Why did he choose thicker arch sections at middle above mid-river and narrow sections at abutment supports? If he chose a  simply supported condition, then for what structural advantage?

EDIT1:

Could it be some combination of arch and beam design?

Between arch abutments it spans 5 pillar span lengths.Treating main structure as a long span Beam bridge simply supported at ends bending moment at mid-span is maximum so midsection should be designed deeply trussed as done here.

However does it not compromise benefits of pure membrane arch action ( like St. Louis Gateway arch, Missouri design as a catenary) creating stress concentration by lower section property utilization?

[Eiffel Rail-Road Bridge Portugal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maria_Pia_Bridge)

"In 1876 they designed the 1,158-foot steel railroad Ponte Maria Pia (Maria Pia Bridge) over the Douro River in Oporto, Portugal".

[image]

Comment: sometimes its about aesthetics too.

Comment: @ Florian F: thanks for the edit.

Comment: Simple support = simpler calculations?  1876 predates calculators, but slide rulers were in full swing.  With increased computation power, quality of materials and understanding of material science, we have been able to refine designs, and cut excess fat from build.  Take a look at your bridge code from the 90s and compare it to your current one.  In my next of the woods the number of pages has more than doubled.  Over build and keep things simple is a hallmark of engineering projects from the past.

Comment: It's hinged at the bottom.  There is no bending at the bottom.

Comment: Hinged at bottom like in sketch  added to the question? Would it not impose extra stress at M, the midspan? The Luis Bridge built soon after Eiffel has fixed connections so maximum bending  there.

Comment: Modern structures use fixed joints because you can use less steel if you have fixed joints. So yes, using hinged joints does mean more stresses somewhere. Hinged joints are easier to analyze. This bridge was held by cables back to the abutments until the arch was joined.

Answer (score 1):

"Why did he choose thicker arch sections at middle above mid-river and narrow sections at abutment supports?"

The greatest force is at the centre of the bridge, not the abutments. Since material is the same strength the thicker sections take higher stresses and therefore greater vertical forces which are transmitted down to the abutments and foundations.

Comment: (When simply  supported maximum bending moment occurs at mid span alright) but in contemporary bridge design typified by the Sydney harbor bridge, sections around supports/piers are built so as to be capable of resisting higher bending moment.

Comment: @Narasimham is 1876 considered contemporary design period?

Answer (score 0):

The picture below is my opinion:

[image]

Comment: Um, I think the question was about the Eiffel Bridge - not the Eiffel Tower!